# How to make the top element of a dropdown open when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown and I am trying to keep just have it open initially when the page loads, then users can click off of it or click on a different element of the dropdown to open another part of it and the original open piece closes. I have my js attempt but so far it doesnt work and has kinda broken my dropdown. I need the top one to look like the two bottom parts of the dropdown just open upon the page loading.

```js
   
                 document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur2(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })
                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var").forEach(d => {
                  d.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    const dropdown = e.target.closest(".dropdown-container-var ").querySelector("ul")
                    if(dropdown) {
                      dropdown.style.display = "block"
                      _ElementBlur2(e.target, () => {
                        dropdown.style.display = "none"
                      })
                    }
                  })
                })

                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(listItem => {
                  listItem.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    window.location.href = e.target.attributes.href.value;
                  })
                })
                document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container-var ul li").forEach(listItem => {
                  listItem.addEventListener("click", e => {
                    window.location.href = e.target.querySelector("a2").getAttribute("href");
                  })
                })



                // Functions for getting a 'blur' event on an element
                const _ElementBlur2 = (el, f = false) => {
                  const ac = new AbortController()
                  document.body.addEventListener("click", _CheckBlur2(el, f, ac), { signal: ac.signal })
                }

                const _CheckBlur2 = (el, f = false, ac) => {
                  return e => {
                    if(!document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).filter(efp => efp == el).length || !document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY).length) {
                      if(f && typeof(f) == "function") f()
                      ac.abort()
                    }
                  }
                }

                const dropdown = document.getElementById("surface_open");

            // add the open attribute to the dropdown element
            dropdown.setAttribute("open", "");
```

```css
   a3 {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    a2 {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;/* Change this to the desired color */
    transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }

    .dropdown-container-var {
      position: relative; /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #333;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
   
        }

    .dropdown-container-var:hover { /* create a positioning context for the list items */
      background-color: #525252;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }


    .dropdown-list-var {
      position: relative; /* position the list items absolutely */
     display: none; /* hide the list by default */

      list-style-type: none; /* remove the bullet points for the list items */
      padding: 0; /* remove the padding for the list */
      left: 0; /* position the list items at the left edge of the list */
      transition: border 0.2s; /* add a transition effect for the border */
      background-color: #b0b0b0;
      color: black;
      text-decoration: none;
    width: 600px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var li:hover {
      background-color: #04AA6D;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;}/* change the background color of the list items 
    to green when they are hovered over */
    }
    .dropdown-list-var li {
      color: black; /* set the color of the list items to black */
        text-align: center;
        transition: background-color 0.2s;
    }
    p2 {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-list-var {
      margin: 0; /* <-- add this to the existing CSS code*/
      /* the rest */
    }
    optgroup {
      font-weight: bold;
      color: black;
      width: 520px;
        cursor: default; 
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Surface and Precipitation</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
          <ul class = "optgroup">
              <select id="surface_open">
          <optgroup label="Surface">
          </ul>
        <li><a2 href="#">2m Temperature</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">2m Dewpoint</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">Mean Sea Level Pressure</a2></li>
          <li><a2 href="#">10m Wind</a2></li>
          </select>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Dynamics</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Vorticity">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">500 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Height,Wind,Vorticity</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container-var">
      <p2><a3 href="#" >Upper-Air: Temperature,Wind</a3></p2>
      <ul class="dropdown-list-var">
                            <ul class = "optgroup">
          <optgroup label="Temperature">
          </ul>
          <li><a2 href="#">700 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">850 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
        <li><a2 href="#">925 hPa Temperature, Height, Wind</a2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You have a malformed `select` element for starters, among many other syntax errors try using https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input to clean up your code. If you still have problems after passing validation come back and update your question. Right now your code is full of problems making it less likely for someone to want to sift through it all.

Comment: @ArleighHix fair, I am brand new to this and I haven't heard of that website yet but thank you for pointing me in the right direction I appreciate it!